# Selecting line between two polygons using MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, spatial-query

Just wondering if its possible to extract a line that between two polygons - hopefully the image illustrates this well - I want to extract Line A-B. I'm using MapInfo.

Currently I've used the Intersect function but it results in the entire polygon being selected. I realize there may be a few steps required here.

[image]

Comment: Here's a related question/answer:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154456/split-polyline-where-it-intersects-with-other-lines-in-mapinfo

Comment: I don't know how to do it with MapInfo but you should convert polygons into lines and then find segments which are equal.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make desired layer editable. Select the polygons A and B. Convert to Polylines.
2. Click on reshape button showing you the nodes. Put SNAP on and draw a polygon       around the line you wanna extract.
3. Now use the Polyline Split option. Now you may save the splited line elsewhere or keep it there.

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up, in the end I create a small buffer of polygon A, converted polygon B to polylines and then selected Polyline B within the Polygon A buffer.

It was a bit crude and labour intensive but good enough for my purposes. Thanks for the responses everyone.